# Throwing error in New-Item in powershell after creating new files

Tags: powershell

I am writing PowerShell script to create new files, but its throwing error at runtime:

```
New-Item -path c:\subhashis -name $input2 -type "file"
```

where `$input2` is runtime parameter I'm passing on

> [DBG]>>> Stopped at: $_.PSParentPath.Replace("Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::", "")

Comment: Why you have kept debugger? what actually it is capturing in $error?

Comment: Try this to create an empty file and see the result `[System.IO.File]::CreateText("E:\EmptyFile.txt")` or with `New-Item C:\subhashis\new_file.txt -type file -force -value "This is text "`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there's an issue with the way you are calling New-Item.  Just a note on syntax:

```
New-Item -ItemType 'File' -Name 'String' -Path 'C:\Temp'
```

Based on your error code, I couldn't tell you exactly what's going wrong in your code without seeing more of it.

Alternatively, you can ignore the name flag and use `-Path "C:\Temp\$filename"` instead.

Comment: I tried to replace the syntax as you mentioned but getting the same error. Here is my code snippet  function test-param {
param ([int]$input1, [String]$input2)
$chunk = 0
foreach($line in $fileinput1) {
    if ($line.substring(0,2) -eq 'Ab')
    {
        $chunk++;
        New-Item -Itemtype 'File' -Path "c:\subhashis\$input2"   
    }

Comment: @SubhashisKhan Don't post code in comments, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44733062/edit) to contain this additional information so follow-up readers don't need to read through all the comments.